# the program performance when using epoll with EPOLLONESHOT in multithread server

Tags: c, multithreading, epoll

the code is so easy, because i use EPOLLONESHOT to create a leader-follower multithread server program.

i run a test for it, and the server just do echo directly.  when the qps reaches 150000, the 12 worker thread falls into D status, but the server has no memory alloc and the disk isn't busy at all.

the server's qps won't raise if i continue to add more test client for it, it just stays at 150000 qps.

this is all my server does, the test client and the server is on the same machine talking through lo(not phyics network card), the cpu idle per cpu is 60, but the performance just don't increase any more, what's the Bottleneck here ?

```
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=28, u64=28}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000051>
read(28, "hello world\n", 4096)         = 12 <0.000005>
write(28, "hello world\n", 12)          = 12 <0.000015>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 28, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=28, u64=4656724694760685596}}) = 0 <0.000033>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=14, u64=14}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000038>
read(14, "hello world\n", 4096)         = 12 <0.000005>
write(14, "hello world\n", 12)          = 12 <0.000013>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 14, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=14, u64=4656724694760685582}}) = 0 <0.000040>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=15, u64=15}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000056>
read(15, "hello world\n", 4096)         = 12 <0.000005>
write(15, "hello world\n", 12)          = 12 <0.000008>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 15, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=15, u64=4656724694760685583}}) = 0 <0.000047>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=33, u64=33}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000039>
read(33, "hello world\n", 4096)         = 12 <0.000004>
write(33, "hello world\n", 12)          = 12 <0.000019>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 33, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=33, u64=4656724694760685601}}) = 0 <0.000039>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=35, u64=35}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000042>
read(35, "hello world\n", 4096)         = 12 <0.000005>
write(35, "hello world\n", 12)          = 12 <0.000010>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 35, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=35, u64=4656724694760685603}}) = 0 <0.000042>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000039>
read(8, "hello world\n", 4096)          = 12 <0.000006>
write(8, "hello world\n", 12)           = 12 <0.000007>
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 8, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLONESHOT, {u32=8, u64=4656724694760685576}}) = 0 <0.000054>
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21, u64=21}}}, 1, 1000) = 1 <0.000034>


13283 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 R   19  0.4   4:33.09 server                                                                   
13288 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   19  0.4   4:33.27 server                                                                   
13286 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   17  0.4   4:32.60 server                                                                   
13287 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   17  0.4   4:34.72 server                                                                   
13280 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   15  0.4   4:33.20 server                                                                   
13281 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   15  0.4   7:50.35 server                                                                   
13282 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 R   15  0.4   4:33.14 server                                                                   
13290 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 R   15  0.4   4:31.80 server                                                                   
13279 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   13  0.4   4:24.11 server                                                                   
13285 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   13  0.4   4:32.91 server                                                                   
13289 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   13  0.4   4:32.34 server                                                                   
13284 work      15   0  636m 256m  308 D   12  0.4   4:31.70 server                                                                   
14042 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S   10  0.0   1:46.98 test_long_conn                                                           
 6403 work      16   0  3692  580  416 S   10  0.0   0:00.12 grep                                                                     
13915 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    8  0.0   1:47.42 test_long_conn                                                           
13930 work      16   0  2380  344  280 R    8  0.0   1:49.59 test_long_conn                                                           
13945 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    8  0.0   1:48.38 test_long_conn                                                           
13841 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    6  0.0   1:36.61 test_long_conn                                                           
13847 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    6  0.0   1:49.55 test_long_conn                                                           
13848 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    6  0.0   1:48.75 test_long_conn                                                           
13849 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    6  0.0   1:48.45 test_long_conn                                                           
13850 work      16   0  2380  344  280 S    6  0.0   1:48.74 test_long_conn                                                           
13913 work      16   0  2380  344  280 R    6  0.0   1:47.50 test_long_conn
```

Comment: 150000 qps is not bad. The fact that it is not CPU-bound (60%) is a nice bonus. You probably wont get much more out of a consumer-box anyway so searching which bottlenecks exist is probably not worth it.

Comment: Btw: which client-simulator are you using? something you wrote yourself too?

Comment: yes, i write a single thread client, and run it with serveral process.

Comment: another problem is that, long-connection can reach 150000, but short-connection can only reach 20000~25000. do you think i should optimize some config in /proc/sys/net, because i have heared that someone can make a short-connection server reaching 80000~100000 qps , which is amazing and unbelivable...

Comment: Please check the numbers you wrote: 150,000 on long connections and 25,000 on short makes no sense, *short* connections should allow *more* connections.

Comment: i'm sure about it, 150,000 on long connections and 25,000 on short connections.  at first, i think the normal connected-fd may use more time in worker thread, thus the listening-fd don't have enough chances to do accepting. so i create a single thread for listening socket which running event loop with a seperate epollfd, and it epoll_ctl(add) the new accepted fd into the worker-thread-pool's epoolfd, but i just stay at the same qps... i have profile the program with valgrind-callgrind, and the result donesn't show me any bad performance in Application layer code.

Comment: Maybe you are measuring *simultaneous connections* and not *queries per second*? (In that case it would make sense, and is ok!)

Comment: i make my server printf("request_finish_time=%d\n", time(NULL)) when finishing a request, and i use "tail -f logfile | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | uniq -c" to stat, i'am missing something, thanks.

Comment: `request_finish_time` sounds like a third metric: ie how much time a single query requires to finish (in milliseconds or cpu-ticks). So now i am a little confused whether you are measuring that or (2) queries-per-second or (3) simultaneous connections.

Comment: it should be (2) queries-per-second, because it unique all lines with the same unix-timestamp and print out the line count.

Comment: That is a strange way of measuring it, also seems to be influenced by the startup-time of the processes. Why dont you just write a client-simulator that runs 10,000 queries in a loop and run 100 processes of them and wait until all are finished. If they finish in 100 seconds then you know that you can handle 10,000 queries per second.

Comment: sorry, i just got home from work, i will try it.